# How to path any values in @RequestParam?

Tags: java, spring

There is rest-controller method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user", method=HttpMethod.POST)
public UserWrapper find(@PathParam(value="name") String name)){
  return userService.find(user);
}
```

and it can return list of user's with found name;

```
POST localhost:8080/user?name=Irina
```

Can I improve service to path names via comma?

```
POST localhost:8080/user?name=Irina,Anna
```

It is simple way to just split(",") of name-string, but it's no good idea I think..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make your parameter to be a list:

```
@RequestParam(value="names") List<String> names
```